# Springboot And AngularIO on ElasticBeansTalk and Shippable

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment, shippable-ci

**Briefing**

I'm having some issue while setting up a Continuous Deployment environment for an application built using SpringBoot and Angular IO, using Shippable as CI and Elastic Beanstalk as production environment.

**The Current Scenario**

1) Application JAR being correctly generated through Shippable (we use heroku as staging)

2) Local JAR correctly generated and manual deploy to Elastic BeansTalk working fine

**The Problem**

My problem is integrating Shippable to automate the deploy to Elastic Beanstalk.
I've followed this tutorial from shippable:

http://blog.shippable.com/how-to-deploy-to-elastic-beanstalk-part-1

and I've finished up with a successfully deploy from Shippable to Elastic Beanstalk, except that Shippable has generated a .zip with the source code (it was actually the purpose of the tutorial and I haven't noticed that hehe) and I need the executable JAR to be deployed on my Elastic Beantalk environment.

**The Specific Question**

So the question: Is there a way to deploy my Springboot executable JAR to Elastic BeansTalk using the built-in Shippable Integration? Or do I have to manually write the steps on `shippable.yml` and use `eb deploy` to make it work?

Thanks a lot!

**Update one**

In this Amazon link:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-artifact

They specify a way to deploy an artifact instead of the source code.
As Shippable calls `eb deploy`, creating the configuration file makes shippable integration calls the deploy on the artifact passed as parameter
to `eb deploy`. I believe it's just a matter of finding where (in file hierarchy) Shippable is calling the `eb deploy`. I though it was from the root of the project but it gives an ERROR:

> ERROR: Application Version does not exist locally
>   (project/backend/target/myjar.jar). Try uploading the
>   Application Version again.

Anyone knows from where shippable calls the commands from the deploy section (configured in shippable.yml, more info in the first link mentioned in this question)?